# Strongloop - Get config values from remote methods or model hooks

Tags: strongloop

I have a node.js project using StrongLoop with config.local.json and config.json files containing config key value pairs.  In server.js I used the following code to retrieve values for keys:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var app = module.exports = loopback();
var value = app.get('key');
```

However, in Model remote methods or model hooks, how can I retrieve these config key values there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is get the already created Loopback application, which has access to the config file, and has loaded it.

```
var app = require('server.js');
var value = app.get('key');
```

Comment: Old question but... Do I need to include the path of the file? Is there no way to use relative paths and such? to avoid ('../../server/server.js')

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the app that's created in server.js then use `get` and `set` accessor methods. These can take 'any' ... I've used collections and scalars, normal JS stuff.

I did find I needed to give the full relative path to the `require` statement. Using Visual Studio Code, this was easy as it kept track of it for me as I typed. It did suggest server.js, so the IDE has no brain, you have to use yours!

In my code, I have server.js in the project directory, and a './common/models 
directory.

Inside one of my observer hooks, I have a file, Rules.js

```
module.exports = function (rules) {
  ...
  // note, no .js needed
  let loopbackApp = require('../../server/server');
```

Then, when I need to update values:

```
console.log('Count:', loopbackApp.get('count'));
loopbackApp.set('count',loopbackApp.get('count')+1);
```

Up in Server.js I have:

```
app.set('count', 0);
```

This works as of 2019, Loopback 3.

Unfortunately, I can't comment, so full credit goes to  @marsairic's answer with a few changes; he helped point me the right way. Upvote his answer too!

```
    == John ==
```